# End NSTimer update in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I have created a little timer in my Swift application that I want to end when the timer is up. I created an else statement to perform a segue when the timer reaches zero. When that happens, it just keeps refreshing the segue every 1 second so the segue never ends. The code runs fine, I just need to end the update `var timer` when the timer reaches 0 so the segue is only performed once instead of over and over again every second. How can I achieve that with the code I have below? I would like this answered in Swift please.

```
var count = 5
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func update() {
        if (count > 0) {
            timer.text = String(count--)
        } else if count == 0 {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("toResults", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you look at the docs for `NSTimer` and see anything that does that?

Comment: Add `timer.invalidate()` when performing the `segue`

Comment: In your `else if`, add `timer = nil`. This may not be the best approach but it should work.

Comment: @WilliamAnderson it will not work as the timer is still registered with a run loop, all you're doing there is killing your link to it...

Comment: This should be obvious but set `repeats` to `false` in your timer initialization.